# How can I create a growing vector of unknown length from given indexes?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

In matlab, I have a matrix `A (n,2)` with n indexes and I want to create a vector that contains all elements between those indexes.

For example:

`A = [10 15; 55 60; 100 105] % Indexes`

Vector V, should look like this:

`V = [10 11 12 13 14 15 55 56 57 58 59 60 100 101 102 103 104 105]`

Length of A and V will be variable in my data. How could I achieve so efficiently?

Thank you

Comment: Indeed, thank you! (I am sorry, I did not find that one).